# Approach to refactor multi-portal solution asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, projects-and-solutions, n-tier-architecture

i am currently refactoring a massive monolithic asp.net mvc solution (which runs as a website/portal) and extracting class libraries with

1. common business logic (that can be used to create a similar portals)
2. core business logic (that can be used as domain logic)
3. common repository logic
4. core repository logic
5. portal specific business logic  (if common business logic doesnt do it)
6. portal specific repository logic (if common repository logic doesnt do it)

the problem with this approach as i see is at the time of introducing similar portals i will have to create their specific business logic layers
and repository logic layers if the need arises and this will increase number of projects in the solution (with fear of it going unmanageable)

how do i achieve multi-portal solution in terms of manageable projects?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been in a similar situation having a bunch of MVC sites sharing a lot of common functionalities.

What we’ve done was first to isolate all those common things in a separate solution (we’ve called it "Global"). This solution is structured almost the same way as all the MVC sites and contains the "Global" specific business logic, interfaces, entities, repositories and UI components as well (i.e.: headers and footers, login functionality, ...). Those common functionalities are organized in [portables areas](http://portableareas.codeplex.com/) that can be deployed, as soon as you need one of them in one of your MVC sites, using a dedicated Nuget package.

In order to be able to test all the portable areas we’ve developed, without the need of deploying them, we’ve created a "launcher" site within the Global sln. This site is never deployed; it has been built only for testing purpose.

Our MVC architecture is not common n-tiers architecture, but [Onion](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) architecture. Please have a look at all the [related StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onion-architecture) to get into if you’re interested.  All our MVC sites are using StructureMap DI in order to bind all the interfaces we used with the right implementation, at start-up.  The Global has its own DI container configuration section. The only thing you have to do to get things running properly, is calling these 2 methods within the Global.asax file of the MVC Site that host the portable areas:

```
GlobalConfig.Init();
GlobalConfig.RegisterAllAreas();
```

The Init method is where StructureMap binds all the interfaces with the right implementation and the RegisterAllAreas methods registers the portable area routes and bundles. These 2 methods must be called before the registration of the MVC site own routes, bundles and DI stuff.

Here’s the Global sln folder structure:

[image: Global sln folder structure]

Web.xxxx projects are all the different portable areas you need to create. It’s better to separate things to avoid having the need to deploy always everything even if your MVC site only needs the user account shared functionalities.

Here’s a closer look at one of the Web.xxxx project structure:

[image: Web.xxxx project structure]

The portable area project is called xxxx.Area, it contains all the views and controllers of the area. It has also the xxxxAreaRegistration.cs which defines the routes and bundles of the area.

The view model and builders are in a separate project called xxxx.ViewModel.

xxxx.Domain and xxxx.DomainModel projects are where all the service implementation and domain model of the area are stored. Xxxx.Data is where the area’s repositories implementations are.

All the areas service and repositories interfaces are stored in the Contract project (see fig.#1) and can be separately deployed with a specific Nuget package.

This was the big picture of the way we organize things here, do not hesitate if you need some more information and details if you want to go with that kind of architecture.

Hope that helps!